# Change brace coding style in QtCreator

Tags: qt, coding-style, qt-creator, braces

I want to change the braces coding style in Qt Creator 2.7.1. Currently, it is:

```
void bar(int i)
{
    static int counter = 0;
    counter += i;
}
```

But I want to change it to:

```
void bar(int i) {
    static int counter = 0;
    counter += i;
}
```

If I go to `Options -> C++ -> Edit -> Braces`, I can only change the indent of the braces. Changing the position of the braces manually in the preview text field, doesn't take any effect.

Comment: This feature doesn't exist. You'd be more than welcome to add it to Qt Creator. The sources are available, download it, build as-is under Qt Creator, then patch away :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Artistic Style Plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/astyleplugin/) for Qt Creator IDE:

1. Download plugin for your Qt Creator IDE version (for v2.7.1 download 2.7.0 version).
2. Unpack.
3. Edit dependency version description in ArtisticStyle.pluginspec into already-installed version:

   - On terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) run `qtcreator -version` to get dependency version.
   - Example version description for v2.7.0:

     ```
     <dependency name="Core" version="2.7.0"/>
     <dependency name="TextEditor" version="2.7.0"/>
     <dependency name="ProjectExplorer" version="2.7.0"/>
     <dependency name="Qt4ProjectManager" version="2.7.0"/>
     ```

     Change to (for v2.7.1):

     ```
     <dependency name="Core" version="2.7.1"/>
     <dependency name="TextEditor" version="2.7.1"/>
     <dependency name="ProjectExplorer" version="2.7.1"/>
     <dependency name="Qt4ProjectManager" version="2.7.1"/>
     ```
4. Follow the normal steps from website to install the plugin.
5. Change the style through Preference -> Artistic… -> Style.
6. Add your own style and add `--style=java`.

Answer (score 3):

I've opened public suggestion at Qt Creator bug tracker -- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11033.

Think, that it would be more helpful to pay more attention to bug tracker.

Hope, this feature will be added in Qt Creator 3.0.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it's not in Qt Creator 3.0

Comment: @barjak Merged in 2014, you need to enable Beautifier in plugins menu.

Answer (score 0):

As of recent Creator versions (not googled when this change was made) this is controlled by clang-format.
[This option](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#alignafteropenbracket) hould control it.

Comment: It does not, `BraceWrapping - AfterFunction` should be used instead. Unfortunately, code added through "Refactor -> Add Definition" menu still has a brace on a separate line...